# Moving the messaging channel from one org to another using changset

Tags: change-set, messaging

I just want to asked if its possible to include messaging channel to outbound changset?

Answer (score 2):

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/59), Messaging channel is not supported in changeset.

[image]